# IAM User Not Authorized to AssumeRole

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sts

I am trying to do role assumption with Java from IAM User auditor of account1 to another AWS account account2 but it always give me the error message as follow:

```
AWSSecurityTokenServiceException: User: arn:aws:iam::account1:user/auditor is not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::account2:role/roleTester (Service: AWSSecurityTokenService; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID: d6cf1458-a3ab-40f4-b24f-f1459a79a82d; Proxy: null)
```

The trust relationship of the role roleTester in account2 that would allow account1 to access the account2's resources is as follows:

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::account1:root"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "sts:ExternalId": "d5d2c143-f6b4-48e9-bd16-8708d86a0152"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Meanwhile, in the IAM User auditor in account1 has the inline policy as follow:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "sts:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::account1:role/AuditorCheck"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "sts:*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Using the access key of IAM user auditor, I tried to run the following code but returned error.

```
BasicAWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials("accesskey", "secretkey"); //Mitigant credential
AWSCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider();
 AWSSecurityTokenService stsClient = AWSSecurityTokenServiceClientBuilder.standard()
                .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credentials)) // IAM User Auditor credential
                .withRegion(Regions.EU_CENTRAL_1) 
                .build();

AssumeRoleRequest roleRequest = new AssumeRoleRequest()
               .withRoleArn("arn:aws:iam::account2:role/roleTester") //the ARN of the role provided by cloud customers
               .withExternalId("d5d2c143-f6b4-48e9-bd16-8708d86a0152")  // the external ID provided by cloud customers
               .withRoleSessionName("test"); 

AssumeRoleResult roleResponse = stsClient.assumeRole(roleRequest);
Credentials sessionCredentials = roleResponse.getCredentials();
BasicSessionCredentials awsCredentials = new BasicSessionCredentials(
               sessionCredentials.getAccessKeyId(),
               sessionCredentials.getSecretAccessKey(),
               sessionCredentials.getSessionToken());
```

Is there something wrong with either of the trust relationship of account2 or the inline policy of account1?

Comment: What `assume-role` command are you using, are you specifiying the right `external-id`?

Comment: How exactly are you assuming the role?

Comment: I used Java SDK for the assume role, i gave the example code in the post

Comment: nothing inherently and obvious wrong, you need to start debugging work. Use the CLI for faster trouble shooting, change the trust relationship, change the inline policy, etc. until you get it to work and pinpoint what change causes it to stop working.

Comment: In terms of the trust relationship of the role in account2, is it ok for using the root rather than specifying the user in account1? @luk2302

Comment: When you specify the root in a trust relationship, you're saying "anyone in this account that has an identity policy that allows them to perform the action". However, for debugging it's certainly worth changing that to specify the exact user.

Comment: Just a tip -- look at using best practice code - AWS SDK for Java v2.  Any AWS Java code that uses the New keyword (to create a request object)  is old V1 and not best practice. See this V2 example:  https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/main/javav2/example_code/sts/src/main/java/com/example/sts/AssumeRole.java